# cmake set variable not added / not used

Tags: bash, terminal, cuda, cmake, torch

I'm missing the variable `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR` to install cutorch.

Although I'm doing `cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="/usr/local/cuda"`it is still missing the variable when I try to install with `luarocks install cutorch`.

I tried to empty the cache. Then on rebuild it says:

```
CMake Warning:
   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR

-- Build files have been written to: /Users/vinni/torch
```

How  can I get the variable to stay?

Comment: isn't `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR` supposed to be an environment variable?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Yes I think so. How can I set it? It's my first time with cmake.

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus macOS Sierra

Comment: I don't use mac's, but I'm pretty sure you can do something to the effect of `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="/usr/local/cuda"; cmake .` or just export the toolkit directory variable.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus hmm, this seems to skip the `were not used...` after I clear the cache. But still giving the error:
    `CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:642 (message):
    Specify CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR`

Comment: Did you install CUDA first? Does `/usr/local/coda` exist on the filesystem?

Comment: @CinderBiscuits I found the problem. Although I had cuda installed, that folder was more or less empty. I reinstalled cuda and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my case the `/usr/local/coda` folder wasn't empty, but there were plenty of files missing. I reinstalled cuda and now everything works. Without rewriting any  variables.

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept your answer so that this question falls off the unanswered queue.